# WebClient DownloadString not returning anything

Tags: c#, webclient, downloadstring

I want to get the source code from a Search query of Pirate Bay, I have this in my code but it doesn't return anything:

```
WebClient webpage = new WebClient();
string source=  webpage.DownloadString("http://thepiratebay.sx/search/documentary/0/99/0");
```

Comment: Must work fine. What your expected result?

Comment: the WebClient works fine, as You get an empty string this is probably a url mistake

Comment: My expected result is the source code from that webpage, but it gets me a empty string

Comment: Do you have a firewall or proxy of anything like that which could be causing an outbound connection to fail, or redirect you to another page?

Comment: No, I dont have a Firewall or antivirus or anything

Comment: Did you try my update ? It solves your problem ... (and if it does, you can select it as the answer)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a quick test:

xaml:

```
<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=window_name, Path=SourceTest}"></Label>
<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=window_name, Path=SourceTest2}"></Label>
```

Code:

```
string source_url = "http://thepiratebay.sx/search/documentary";

WebClient webpage = new WebClient();
SourceTest = webpage.DownloadString(source_url);
if (SourceTest == "")
SourceTest = "stream was empty.";


source_url = "http://www.google.com";

webpage = new WebClient();
SourceTest2 = webpage.DownloadString(source_url);
if (SourceTest2 == "")
    SourceTest2 = "stream was empty.";
```

Your URL will return an empty string, Google on the other side, will give you the source you're looking for.

**Edit :**
As I assumed, you need to identify like a web browser. This works with your query:

```
string source_url = "http://thepiratebay.sx/search/documentary/0/99/0";

using (var webpage = new WebClient())
{
    webpage.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2";
    SourceTest = webpage.DownloadString(source_url);
}
```

Comment: using `string source_url = "http://thepiratebay.sx/` will work, so my guess is that they might be filtering requests from non browsers maybe?

Comment: @Noctis your solution to add userAgent in header is worked for me absolutely.

Comment: @HaiderAliWajihi Yep, because you fool the pirate bay to think you're a browser :). Glad it helped.